# Awk doesn`t work when it run at other path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, path

> ./oppa/loadParesr/spliter.sh [filename]

*spliter.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh
sort -k 1V,1 -k 2n,2 $1 -o $1
awk `{close(f);f=$1}{print > f".bed"}`
```

---

i try to run this shell at other path. sort command work well but 
awk is doesn't work and i don't know why.

Comment: "doesn't work" does not describe the issue; please be more specific.

Comment: Replace both backticks by single quotes.

Comment: Btw.: sh is not bash.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for answer. now it is perfect... now i shamed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the file you're writing to, not just part of it's name, and always quote your shell variables, for example:

```
awk '{close(f); f=$1".bed"; print > f}' "$1"
```